# How to handle partial matching on key in Python

Tags: python

### What to do

Hope to combine information from both the given sentence and existing dictionary in NLP.

Key words are expected nouns and extract determiners, like `the` and `some`.

```
#input
text = "Many plates and glasses are in the washing machine. These plates are my favourite."
keywords = ['plate', 'glass', 'washing machine']
#existing data
dic = {'plate':'red', 'glass':'transparent', 'machine':'gray'}
```

### Output and Error

I would like to know how to solve the problem to get preferred output related to partial matching issue.

Hope to add elements of part of compound words, in this case, `machine`'s element to the key `washing machine`'s element.

I don't want to create new key, but to do partial matching between the key 'machine`and`washing machine`.

output

```
{'plate': [], 'glass': [], 'washing machine': []}
plate Some
{'plate': ['Some'], 'glass': [], 'washing machine': []}
machine the
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 51, in <module>
    result[token.head.lemma_].append(token.text)
KeyError: 'machine'
```

### Output from the first trial

Hope not to add new key 'machine', but to add `machine`'s elements to `washing machine`.

```
{'plate': ['Some', 'These', 'red'], 'glass': ['transparent'],
 'washing machine': [], 'machine': ['the', 'gray']}
```

Expected output

```
#output
{'plate':['red', 'some'], 'glass':['transparent', 'some'],
 'washing machine':['gray', 'the'] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the the following section in your code:

```
        if k == target_k:
            result[k].append(dic[k])
```

into

```
        if k == target_k:
            result[k] = result.get(k, [])
            result[k].append(dic.get(k, None))
```

---

similarily,

```
result[token.head.lemma_].append(token.text)
```

into

```
result[token.head.lemma_] = result.get(token.head.lemma_, [])
result[token.head.lemma_].append(token.text)
```

Comment: @DevCI9 Thank you for your answer. My question was not clear enough, so I fix it a bit.

Comment: @Mahler I have also updated the answer. please check

Comment: @DevCI9 Thank you again. I've tried to execute it, but still my prefferd output was not gained.